# Error 9 "Subscript out of range" trying to access an element of a variant array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to access the elements of an array created through a range, but for some reason I'm getting a value out of range error.

```
Sub Macro1()

        Dim xRng As Range

        Dim x() As Variant

                Set xRng = Range("B2:B12")

                x() = xRng.Value
                MsgBox ("x = " <> CStr(x(3)))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the 2nd indice in `x(3)`. Try `x(3, 1)`. The variable is a 2D variant array addressed by (row, column).

**EDIT** To reduce your array to rank 1, you'd have to go something along those lines:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim xRng As Range
    Dim x2D As Variant
    Dim x1D As Variant
    Dim l As Long

    Set xRng = Range("B2:B12")
    x2D = xRng.Value

    ReDim x1D(LBound(x2D, 1) To UBound(x2D, 1))
    For l = LBound(x1D) To UBound(x1D)
        x1D(l) = x2D(l, 1)
    Next

    MsgBox ("x = " <> CStr(x1D(3)))
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you, is there any way I can reduce x to rank 1?

Comment: Also see [Convert range to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53434664/convert-range-to-an-array/53434726#53434726) for the particular case of a single-cell range.

Answer (score 1):

You have to transpose the 2D array resulting out of a some1ColumnedRange.Value to have a 1D array:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim xRng As Range
    Dim x As Variant

    Set xRng = Range("B2:B12")

    x = Application.Transpose(xRng.Value) ' this way you get a 1D array
    MsgBox ("x = " <> CStr(x(3)))
End Sub
```

Comment: Arrgh! I keep forgetting about this trick. Upvoted. Note that you have to remove the parentheses when assigning to x. Nitpicking: your single apostrophe in front of the comment isn't the char Excel expects.

Comment: @Excelosaurus, thanks for the apostrophe niptick:I was by the cellphone and I can't have proper quotation marks or single apostrophe